# is any risk/notes to write output to different folders using mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

The goal is to write output to different folders(different path) using one reduce.
I use old mapreduce api, and I do a little modification on MultipleOutputs(loose the restriction), and it works.
But the outputformat I use extends FileOutputFormat, where FileOutputCommitter is refered by FileOutputFormat.
And I find there will be a _success file in only one folder. it will be a problem?

And there still a empty file part-00000, I don't know why it is generated?

Answer (score 0):

_SUCCESS is written only once after the job is complete. It is useful to check if the job is complete. I dont think there is any risk with that. You should know that it is created only after the job is complete and you should know where to look for that file if you are using it.

Regarding the part- files, take a look at 
[map reduce output files: part-r-* and part-*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924852/map-reduce-output-files-part-r-and-part)