# Renaming Part Files in Hadoop Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have tried to use the `MultipleOutputs` class as per the example in page http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.21.0/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Driver Code

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Wordcount");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
            Text.class, IntWritable.class);
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Reducer Code

```
public class WordCountReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    private MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable> mos;
    public void setup(Context context){
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable>(context);
    }
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        //context.write(key, result);
        mos.write("text", key,result);
    }
    public void cleanup(Context context)  {
         try {
            mos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         }
}
```

The output of the reducer is found to rename to text-r-00000

But the issue here is that I am also getting an empty part-r-00000 file as well. Is this how MultipleOutputs is expected to behave, or is there some problem with my code? Please advice.

Another alternative I have tried out is to iterate through my output folder using the FileSystem  class and manually rename all files beginning with part.

What is the best way?

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
FileStatus fs[] = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(outputPath));
for (FileStatus aFile : fs) {
if (aFile.isDir()) {
hdfs.delete(aFile.getPath(), true);
// delete all directories and sub-directories (if any) in the output directory
} 
else {
if (aFile.getPath().getName().contains("_"))
hdfs.delete(aFile.getPath(), true);
// delete all log files and the _SUCCESS file in the output directory
else {
hdfs.rename(aFile.getPath(), new Path(myCustomName));
}
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even if you are using `MultipleOutputs`, the default `OutputFormat` (I believe it is `TextOutputFormat`) is still being used, and so it will initialize and creating these `part-r-xxxxx` files that you are seeing.

The fact that they are empty is because you are not doing any `context.write` because you are using `MultipleOutputs`. But that doesn't prevent them from being created during initialization.

To get rid of them, you need to define your `OutputFormat` to say you are not expecting any output. You can do it this way:

```
job.setOutputFormat(NullOutputFormat.class);
```

With that property set, this should ensure that your part files are never initialized at all, but you still get your output in the `MultipleOutputs`.

You could also probably use `LazyOutputFormat` which would ensure that your output files are only created when/if there is some data, and not initialize empty files. You could do i this way:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat; 
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Note that you are using in your `Reducer` the prototype `MultipleOutputs.write(String namedOutput, K key, V value)`, which just uses a default output path that will be generated based on your `namedOutput` to something like: `{namedOutput}-(m|r)-{part-number}`. If you want to have more control over your output filenames, you should use the prototype `MultipleOutputs.write(String namedOutput, K key, V value, String baseOutputPath)` which can allow you to get filenames generated at runtime based on your keys/values.

Comment: @ Charles: I had seen the use of LazyOutputFormat in the below post, but I did not know how to use that. Thanks a lot for the reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924852/map-reduce-output-files-part-r-and-part?rq=1

Comment: @Charles: when i try to use 'NullOutputFormat', then even the MultipleOutputs is not written to the output path... does it make sense, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11):

This is all you need to do in the Driver class to change the basename of the output file:
    `job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", "text");`
So this will result in your files being called "text-r-00000".