# Do away with default output directory completely - MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, output, hdfs, cloudera

I have a code for writing multiple outputs using `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs`.

The Reducer writes the results to a pre-created location so I don't require the default o/p directory (which contains the `_history` and `_SUCCESS`  directories).

I have to delete them everytime before running my job again.

So I removed the `TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1,new Path(outputPath));` line. But, this gives me the 
(expected) error `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set`

Driver Class:

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job1, "path1", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class,LongWritable.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job1, "path2", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class,LongWritable.class);
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job1,TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Reducer Class:

```
if(condition1)
    mos.write("path1", key, new LongWritable(value), path_list[0]);
else
    mos.write("path2", key, new LongWritable(value), path_list[1]);
```

Is, there a workaround to avoid specifying a default output directory?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `_SUCCESS` is a directory and the other `history` directory resides inside `_logs` directory.

First of all `TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1,new Path(outputPath));` is important because when the job is run this path is taken as a work directory by Hadoop to create temporary files and such for different tasks (_temporary dir). This _temporary directory and files eventually gets deleted at the end of the job. The file _SUCCESS and history directory is actually what remains under work directory and kept after the job has finished successfully. _SUCCESS file is kind of a flag saying the job actually ran successfully. Please look [at this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputCommitter.java).

The creation of your file **_SUCCESS** is done by  `TextOutputFormat` class, you are actually using, which in turn uses `FileOutputComitter` class. That FileOutputCommiter class defines a function such as this --

```
 public static final String SUCCEEDED_FILE_NAME = "_SUCCESS";
/**
   * Delete the temporary directory, including all of the work directories.
   * This is called for all jobs whose final run state is SUCCEEDED
   * @param context the job's context.
   */
  public void commitJob(JobContext context) throws IOException {
    // delete the _temporary folder
    cleanupJob(context);
    // check if the o/p dir should be marked
    if (shouldMarkOutputDir(context.getConfiguration())) {
      // create a _success file in the o/p folder
      markOutputDirSuccessful(context);
    }
  }

// Mark the output dir of the job for which the context is passed.
  private void markOutputDirSuccessful(JobContext context)
  throws IOException {
    if (outputPath != null) {
      FileSystem fileSys = outputPath.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());
      if (fileSys.exists(outputPath)) {
        // create a file in the folder to mark it
        Path filePath = new Path(outputPath, SUCCEEDED_FILE_NAME);
        fileSys.create(filePath).close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Since, markOutputDirSuccessful() is private, you have to instead override commitJob() to bypass the **SUCCEEDED_FILE_NAME** creation process and achieve what you want.

The next directory **_logs** is very important if you want to later use hadoop HistoryViewer to actually get a report of how the Job ran.

I think, when you use the same output directory as an input to another Job, the file *_SUCCESS* and directory *_logs* will get ignored due to *Filter* set in Hadoop.

**Moreover, when you define a namedoutput for MultipleOutputs, you can instead write to a subdirectory inside the outpath you mentioned in the TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath() function and then use that path as input to the next job you'll be running.**

I don't actually see how _SUCCESS and _logs will every bother you?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Question is pretty old, still sharing an answer,

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555515/1254903) answer suits good for the scenario in the question.

Define your OutputFormat to say you are not expecting any output. You can do it this way:

```
job.setOutputFormat(NullOutputFormat.class);
```

or

you could also probably use `LazyOutputFormat`

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat; 
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Credits @charlesmenguy

Answer (score 1):

What version of Hadoop are you running?

For a quick workaround you could set an output location programmatically and call FileSystem.delete to remove it on job completion.

Comment: I am using CDH4. That's what I do currently. I just wanted to know if there is a way to tweak it not to write at all.