# Need help on Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am executing a Pig script, which reads files from a directory, performs some operation and stores to some output directory. In output directory I'm getting one or more "part" files, one _SUCCESS file and one _logs directory. My questions are:

1. Is there any way to control the name of files generated (upon execution of STORE command) in output directory. To be specific, I don't want the names to be "part-.......". I want Pig to generate files according to the file name pattern I specify.
2. Is there any way to suppress the _SUCCESS file and the _log directory? Basically I don't want the _SUCCESS and _logs to be generated in the output directory.

Regards
Biswajit

Answer (score 0):

1. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555313/renaming-part-files-in-hadoop-map-reduce).
2. To remove _SUCCESS, use `SET mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs false;`. I'm not 100% sure how to remove _logs but you could try `SET pig.streaming.log.persist false;`.