# Change output file name in Spark Streaming

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark job which performs extremely well as far as the logic goes. However, the name of my output files are in the format part-00000,part-00001 etc., when I use saveAsTextFile to save the files in a s3 bucket. Is there a way to change the output filename?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming Part Files in Hadoop Map Reduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555313/renaming-part-files-in-hadoop-map-reduce)

Comment: it is best to do this using shell instead of in Spark. For example, you could potentially collect everything into 1 file by using `coalesce`but it puts strain on the memory - also, hdfs works slightly different from a regular file system, and Spark always create a different destination/folder for each output.

Comment: isnt it this kind of... https://gist.github.com/mlehman/df9546f6be2e362bbad2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spark, you can use **saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile** and set **mapreduce.output.basename** parameter in hadoop configuration to change the prefix (Just the "part" prefix)

```
val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
hadoopConf.set("mapreduce.output.basename", "yourPrefix")

yourRDD.map(str => (null, str))
        .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(s"$outputPath/$dirName", classOf[NullWritable], classOf[String],
          classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, String]], hadoopConf)
```

Your files will be named like: **yourPrefix-r-00001**

In hadoop and Spark, you can have more than one file in the output since you can have more than one reducer(hadoop) or more than one partition(spark). Then you need to warranty unique names for each of them, that is why it is not possible to override the sequence number at the last part of the filename.

But if you want to have more control of your filename, you can extend **TextOutputFormat** or **FileOutputFormat** and override the **getUniqueFile** method.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can we save the files to a s3 bucket instead of hdfs?

Comment: Yes you can, Amazon S3 is compliant with Hadoop API.

Comment: Hadoop FileSystem implement several protocols/file systems including S3: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3. You can use any of those almost transparent (You just need to specify the specific parameters for each kind of connection).If you think my answer helped you with your original question please accept it.

Comment: can you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703623/how-to-rename-spark-data-frame-output-file-in-aws-in-spark-scala

Comment: I think it's `getUniqueName` now. Is there a way I can use a field from the row as a filename, e.g. id?

Answer (score 1):

[Solution in Java]

Lets say you have :

```
JavaRDD<Text> rows;
```

And you want to write it to files like `customPrefix-r-00000` .

```
Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
hadoopConf.set("mapreduce.output.basename", "customPrefix");

rows.mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2(null, row)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputPath, NullWritable.class, Text.class, TextOutputFormat.class, hadoopConf);
```

Tada!!

Comment: Hi, I tried setting basename and it doesn't work: job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", inputStrategyName);
        javaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputPath, new AvroKey<T>().getClass(), NullWritable.class, AvroKeyOutputFormat.class, job.getConfiguration());

Comment: What's the class of job object ?
Just make a new configuration object of this class : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;