# Is it possible to dynamically name the part-XXXX files based on the value of the column used to partition the Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have a `val dataset = Dataset[FeedData]`, where `FeedData` is something like `case class FeedData(feed: String, data: XYZ)`.

I want to avoid post-processing the files, so I decided to call `dataset.repartition($"feed").json("s3a://...")` so that each `feed` ends up in a different file. The problem is that the files are still named along the lines of `part-XXXX` so I can't easily pick out the relevant file for a given feed, without a) opening them all to check the values for `feed` inside, or b) post-processing the files to be more friendly.

**I want the files to look like `part-XXXX-{feed}` instead of `part-XXXX`**

Is it possible to dynamically name the partition files based on the value of the column `feed` used to partition the dataset?

Background:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973939/2217661) answer which mentions a `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile()` method, where I can extend some relevant classes for my own file naming implementation.

Can anybody help me understand this method, how to access it from a `Dataset`, and tell me whether it's possible to project the required information (`feed`) into my implementation to dynamically name the partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do it the wrong way:

`dataset.repartition($"colName").write.format("json").save(path)`

The correct way to do this is:

`dataset.write.partitionBy("colName").format("json").save(path)`

---

The difference is that you should call `.partitionBy` **after** `.write`. The resulting directories look like: `colName=value/part-XXXX`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060188/pre-partition-data-in-spark-such-that-each-partition-has-non-overlapping-values) for more info.

Comment: They actually serve quite different purposes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby/40417992